# How to avoid unnecessary tags when use Heat in wix

Tags: wix, heat

I'm using HEAT to auto generate WiX fragments for a directory of files. 
When the --.wxs file creating, why it include some unnecessary tags within the component?
like follows

scenario 1

```
 <Component Id="cmpFF03591E2D2B9B2AA2AA444299A693DB" Directory="dir7307A6085BD4ABD9B8955C093FD541F5" Guid="*">
   <Class Id="{00AB5D3B-4FAB-35AB-8916-59EE0247EFF1}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSourceElement" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
     <ProgId Id="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSourceElement" Description="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSourceElement" />
   </Class>
   <Class Id="{0ED3627E-5196-3A33-8EDC-7DC7DFCE3A97}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ByteArrayTypeConverter" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
     <ProgId Id="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ByteArrayTypeConverter" Description="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ByteArrayTypeConverter" />
   </Class>
   <Class Id="{10FA9802-2D3A-3CE4-95BB-7170AA4AE251}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ConfigurationChangeEventSourceImpl" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
     <ProgId Id="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ConfigurationChangeEventSourceImpl" Description="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ConfigurationChangeEventSourceImpl" />
   </Class>
```

...........lots of class files

```
 <File Id="fil7DC27EB4CA5B9970A7CBD422D919CCFF" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\bin\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" />
   <ProgId Id="Record" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00AB5D3B-4FAB-35AB-8916-59EE0247EFF1}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00AB5D3B-4FAB-35AB-8916-59EE0247EFF1}\InprocServer32\5.0.414.0" Name="Class" Value="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSourceElement" Type="string" Action="write" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00AB5D3B-4FAB-35AB-8916-59EE0247EFF1}\InprocServer32\5.0.414.0" Name="Assembly" Value="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Type="string" Action="write" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{00AB5D3B-4FAB-35AB-8916-59EE0247EFF1}\InprocServer32\5.0.414.0" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v2.0.50727" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

..........lots of Registry keys

```
</Component>
```

Comment: there is an another scenario like follow                            scenario 2
<Component Id="cmp8881C49A46B392150B03542DCE92B4F9" Directory="dir7307A6085BD4ABD9B8955C093FD541F5" Guid="*">
    <File Id="filC4F1AC6BCC527A213767C3D4E4442B24" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\bin\Modules.Manage.Service.Deployment.dll" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
  </Component>

Answer (score 5):

I will copy paste the answer from my question ([Wix\heat.exe strange output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982426/wix-heat-exe-strange-output)) because it worked for me. As Yan Sklyarenko said:

```
Supply heat.exe with -sreg and -scom command line switches. See heat.exe -? for more options
```

Comment: Thank you to reply. I have create the wix installer project in vs and i have add the auto generate components by heat in the .wixproj file like follows...can you pls tel me where i want to add the command lines                                         <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <HeatDirectory DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" OutputFile="Source.wxs" Directory="D\Releases\Claim" SuppressRootDirectory="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" AutogenerateGuids="true" ComponentGroupName="SourceComponentGroup" PreprocessorVariable="var.SourcePath" SuppressRegistry="false">
    </HeatDirectory>
  </Target>

Comment: I have no idea. I am using the heat.exe directly.

Answer (score 1):

The Classes and Registries means the binaries is a COM binary. it's a C# COM binary since I can see ForeignServer="mscoree.dll".

if you don't want a COM binary, you can specify in your project assemlyinfo.cs marking COMVisible = false.